# Eclipse Profiling with TDTD - possible heap problems

Tags: java, eclipse, profiling

I am currently trying to do a Execution Time Analysis using TDTD and Eclipse 3.7 Indigo. The application being profiled is a 1k test cases big test suite which runs for something around 10min when run under normal run configuration.

[image: JVisualVM Screenshot - Profile Run is terminated at 13:35]

This is a screenshot of the JVisualVM profile of Eclipse while trying to profile the test suite. The profiling run was terminated at 13:35. As can be seen after around 5 minutes the profiling hits some kind of ceiling and events per second drop to a minimum (few hundred per second). I already increased the available heap space of Eclipse to 3gb. PermGen space is available up to 512mb, but stays around 120mb so that does not seem to be the issue.

Usually heap space consumption goes up to around 750mb during a normal test run. More importantly after a normal run the heap space is freed almost instantly whereas the heap space stays allocated even after the termination of profiling.

Used JRE is 1.5.0.16.

Eclipse VMParameters:
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms196m
-Xmx3072m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Run Parameters:
-Xms512m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Any idea how to make this work or find the weak link?